# Retrieving records with the same ID where the number of occurrences of one value in a column is greater than occurrences of another value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry if the title question is unclear, I'd imagine this has been asked before but I've searched for a while and I think I'm just not phrasing it particularly well.

I have a table of call records in which we record when the call is put on hold or picked up from hold. The `callid` column is how we refer to specific calls -- it's not the unique record id so there are multiple entries for the same `callid` when the call is on or off of hold. We record that information in the `answered` column which contains either a 0 for the call being on hold, or 1 for being picked up.

I'm trying to find situations where somebody was put on hold and then hangs up before the call is picked up again; that is, the last occurrence of that particular `callid` should have a 0 in the `answered` column. I started with this query:

```
SELECT * from table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 from table t2
    WHERE t1.callid = t2.callid
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN answered = 1 THEN 1 END)
)
order by id desc
```

However, this doesn't cover situations where the call was put on hold, answered at some point, then put on hold again before the caller hung up. In those instances we'd have three records of the same `callid`, with 0 -> 1 -> 0 in the `answered` column. The best way I can think to do this is to find records with the same `callid` where the number of entries with 0 in the `answered` column is greater than those with a 1. Two questions arise from this:

1. Is there a better way to think about this query?
2. How would I go about looking for that particular scenario? I'd assume I would need to do some counting and comparisons but I haven't yet been able to land on something that works. Thanks and feel free to let me know if any of this needs clarification.

Comment: get the last with row_number or max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Updated `answered = 0` outside of subquery.

`ROW_NUMBER()` is going to be your friend on this one. You can use it determine all the scenarios where the **last entry** for a particular callid = 0. I'm assuming there's some timestamp for each event that occurs.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        callid
        ,... --Other columns needed
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY callid ORDER BY <timestamp column> DESC) AS rn --Order descending so the latest entry = 1
    FROM t1
) as calls
where calls.rn = 1
and answered = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the quick reply. I used this query and it seems I'm getting  records that are the opposite of what I'm looking for. The ones I've tested so far are records in which "1" is the most recent value for that callid. Here's my query:
`SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT id, callid, answered,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY callid ORDER BY time DESC)AS rn
    FROM table
    WHERE answered = 0
    ) AS calls
WHERE calls.rn = 1`

Did I miss something in my implementation of this?

Comment: I missed something. The `answered = 0` needs to be moved out of the subquery. Here's a DB Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73ba7d7a6f6e6db949dae688058adb6c

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look through the fiddle and my data here and see how everything looks.

Comment: This seems to be working great for all situations that I've tested it, thanks again for the help. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since the records always alternate 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, etc, a call whose last action was to be put on hold, ie 0, will have an *odd* number of rows.

Find rows having an odd count:

```
SELECT * from table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from table t2
    WHERE t1.callid = t2.callid
    HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 = 1
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Or as a join, which will perform better:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT callid
    from table
    GROUP BY callid
    HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 = 1
) t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.callid = t1.callid
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a good, clear approach that I didn't think of. As it turns out when I tested it, we do have some records where the number of entries is odd but the last entry is 1, e.g. 0 -> 1 -> 1 for the same callid. That shouldn't be happening but I guess it's something I'll have to work around when figuring out the query.

Comment: A 1 -> 1 sequence is impossible to really happen, therefore such data cannot be relied upon. You should ignore or fix such data.

Comment: I agree with that and the 1 -> 1 comes up often enough that I'm sure there's some other issue with our system. For now I'm going to go with the other answer since I don't have any authority to ask for an investigation of that issue, so it's easier for me to justify an approach that automatically omits the erroneous data.

Comment: @evan you "don't have authority"??? The responsible thing to do is raise a bug report, and if you have the responsibility to do that you automatically have the authority to do that. If other people ignore your bug report that's their prerogative, but they do so at their own peril because the existence of corrupted data could be the tip of the iceberg of a far more serious problem. The data exists to help the business make decisions. If the data is no good then they will unwittingly make incorrect decisions, which is bad.

Comment: That's a good point and I've now brought that data up to other people on the development team so the issue can be investigated. The entries appear often enough that I'm hopeful it'll be looked into. Thanks.